# Did German or English form of infinitive appear first?

Tags: english, german, word-formation, infinitive

German and English languages have a common root but an innumerable amount of differences. One of them is how infinitive is formed. In English we have to+verb: "to stand" in German we have a verb ending with "en": "stehen".

I would like to know which of these two forms appeared first, and if there was any time when they co-existed in the same language at the same time.

Comment: In Old English, the infinitive ended in _-an_. German is much more conservative about retaining Germanic endings than English.

Comment: There seem to be certain circumstances under which German verbs in the infinitive appear with *zu*, which has the same meaning as English *to*. However it's not considered part of the infinitive form as in English.

Comment: @hippietrail, oh I have not thought about this. You are right. It actually makes the whole question less meaningful. It's not difficult to imagine that the only reason to include 'to' to indicate infinitive in English is exactly because it lost the infinitive endings German relies on.

Comment: @hippietrail Yeah you're right. It happens in one of the sentences I memorized when learning German: *Es ist schwierig auf Deutsch **zu sprechen*** = It's difficult **to speak** in German.

Comment: The *to* is not an obligatory part of the infinitive in English. What exactly it ***is*** is controversial, but the 'bare' plain form is called an infinitive, too - for instance, when it is the complement of a modal.

Comment: It's the difference between (1) the infinitive 'bare' form of every verb -- it's identical to the present tense in every case except _be_; (2) a full infinitive clause, with subject and full _for...to_ complementizer (_For him to leave early would be unwise_); and (3) a reduced infinitive clause, usually without _for_ or a subject (and therefore often called a "phrase"), but with a complementizer _to_ (_It was a bad idea to leave early_). This last is all that most people recognize as "an infinitive". (2) is the basic form; (3) is reduced from (2); and they both use the same verb form (1).

Comment: @hippietrail *To* has been a separate word as long as it's been around.

Comment: @snailboat: Well yeah but of course now you're going to have to define "word", and I haven't said anything to counter that. I've personally always found it unnatural to claim "to" to be part of the infinitive form but that doesn't stop it from being widely stated to be the case. I would rather just call it a particle, and one in its own category.

Comment: @jlawler: Well it seems plausible to look at the modal verbs as infinitives too: *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *shall*, *should*, *would*, *will*. Then of course "infinitive" literally means not finite and participles are also not finite. Then there's the times the to seems to bind to a preceding verb rather than a following one: *going to*, *have to*, *want to*, etc. Especially shown by the colloquial contractions *gonna* and *wanna*.

Comment: @hippietrail: if you call modal auxiliaries infinitives then you allow double modals, and ungrammatical sentences like _*I want to can do that_, with or without _to_. The actual forms are roots, with non-functional preterite decorations added on _might, could, should, would,_ and _must_. They all **hafta** be auxiliaries, and they all **hafta** be followed by an infinitive verb form. But they're either present tense or no tense at all, depending on what syntactic church you go to.

Comment: It is quite plausible that the construction "to stand" / "zu stehen" in English and German is inherited from a common protolanguage (in this case, proto-west-germanic), so they are of the same age. English lost the infinitive ending later on, as other commentators already stated.